getting error : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test on project dockerProject_sdet2
pom.xml:

4.0.0
<groupId>dockerProject_sdet2</groupId>
<artifactId>dockerProject_sdet2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>dockerProject_sdet2</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

**error msg **

Source not found for 1:31 morg.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException:
i tried surefire plugin 3.0.0-M5 but getting same result.
C:\Users\Admin>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.3 (21122926829f1ead511c958d89bd2f672198ae9f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.9.3
Java version: 11.0.21, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
C:\Users\Admin>java -version
java version "11.0.21" 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.21+9-LTS-193, mixed mode)
i run successfully testng.xml.2 tcs are passed but unable to run pom.xml

i want to run pom.xml with docker grid project
how to resolve this ,i tried all possible way
I saw all solution related to my que but it didnt work for me

here i am tried to close all command prompt thats why i am getting this issue.after comment on this below line issue is resolved
// Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ;
Now issue is solved
